# Regexp extract text beween two tags

Tags: java, regex

I try to parse a text like

```
0:ID IN (1002,25);1:ID IN (2,3,4) AND COQ>=0 AND COQ<=9;2:ID IN
(73150,73150) AND TOTAL>=0 AND TOTAL<=99999
```

in Java. I need the text content between the numbers including the colon and the semicolon or eol:

```
0:<--this-->;1:<--this-->;2:<--this-->
```

> - ID IN (1002,25)
> - ID IN (2,3,4) AND CO>=0 AND CO<=9
> - ID IN (73150,73150) AND TOTAL>=0 AND TOTAL<=99999

an additional problem occurs because it is possible that whitespaces will be between the numbers and the colons

```
 0    :ID IN (1002,25);   1   :ID IN (2,3,4) AND COQ>=0 AND COQ<=9;2:ID IN
(73150,73150) AND TOTAL>=0 AND TOTAL<=99999
```

i tried `(?<=[\d]:).*(?=;|$)` and `(?<=:).*(?=;|$)`

but both terms does not solve the problem, because they ignore digits with colons between the first and last appearance:

- ID IN (1002,25);   1   :ID IN (2,3,4) AND COQ>=0 AND COQ<=9;2:ID IN
     (73150,73150) AND TOTAL>=0 AND TOTAL<=99999

and they would not ignore digits with colons placed in captions (next problem but in my case a minor one):

```
 0    :NAME = '3:;' OR NAME = "0 :  ;" ;   1   :CO>=0;2:TOTAL<=99999
```

> - NAME = '3:;' OR NAME = "0 :  ;"
> - CO>=0
> - TOTAL<=99999

i would be very cool, if you have a good advice to solve this tricky problem. merci merci pavoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a more complex regex like this to consider all your corner cases:

```
(?:^\s*(?!\s*\d+\s*:)|\d+\s*:)((?:'[^']*'|"[^"]*"|[^;])+)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tT7yR0/2)

The `(?:^\s*(?!\s*\d+\s*:)|\d+\s*:)` subpattern matches the starting subtexts (beginning of string with optional whitespace not followed by optional whitespace, digits, optional whitespace and a colon, or digits followed by optional whitespace and a colon), and then either characters other than `;`, or strings inside `"..."` or `'...'`.

[IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/2bMuzo):

```
String s = "0:ID IN (1002,25);1:ID IN (2,3,4) AND COQ>=0 AND COQ<=9;2:ID IN (73150,73150) AND TOTAL>=0 AND TOTAL<=99999";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:^\\s*(?!\\s*\\d+\\s*:)|\\d+\\s*:)((?:\'[^\']*\'|\"[^\"]*\"|[^;])+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
System.out.println("Match 1:\n");
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Playing with lookarounds, this one should suit your needs:

```
(?<=:).*?(?=;|$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Visualization by [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/z22D01CkdfWTvlsA)

Demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vU1cM8/1)

Don't forget to enable [the dotall mode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL).

---

In Java:

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=:).*?(?=;|$)", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(yourInputString);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following regex:

```
\d+\s*:([^;]+)
```

The captured group is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can split your string in this way:

```
String parts[] = s.split(";?\\s*\\d+\\s*:");
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution, but i am need to replace the `0:` in the first array element.

```
String s = "0    :NAME = '3:;' OR NAME = \"0 :  ;\" ;   1   :CO>=0;2:TOTAL<=99999";

for (String s2 : s.split(";\\s*\\d\\s*:")) {
     System.out.println(s2.replaceAll("^(\\s*\\d\\s*:)", ""));
}

s = "0:ID IN (1002,25);1:ID IN (2,3,4) AND COQ>=0 AND COQ<=9;2:ID IN (73150,73150) AND TOTAL>=0 AND TOTAL<=99999";

for (String s2 : s.split(";\\s*\\d\\s*:")) {
    System.out.println(s2.replaceAll("^(\\s*\\d\\s*:)", ""));
}
```

From what i see it should be getting the correct results.

Comment: You can replace `;` for `(?:$|;)` so it will also split that one but that will leave you with an empty string.